# Nested life times

Tags: lifetime, rust

I'm a bit stumped. I want following code to pass.

```
enum Source<'self> {
    String(&'self str),
    ReaderUtil(&'self ReaderUtil)
}

pub struct Matrix<'self> {
      source: &'self Source
}

fn main() {

}
```

I started with just enum, but then because I needed to use `&`pointers, I had to give it a lifetime. Problem appeared when I added that enum to another struct. I know I can't give struct other lifetime than `'self` but it gives me an error for lifetime, saying anonymous lifetimes aren't allowed in Source (which is same like I didn't add any lifetimes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum Source<'self> {
    String(&'self str),
    ReaderUtil(&'self ReaderUtil)
}

pub struct Matrix<'self> {
      source: &'self Source<'self>
}

fn main() {

}
```

You declared your enum Source with a lifetime parameter, `enum Source<'self>`. That means you also have to declare the lifetime for Source in Matrix.

Comment: Put more explicitly, just as with type generics like `Foo<T>` where `Foo` is not a valid type without the `<T>`, `Source` is not a valid type without specifying its lifetime, such as `Source<'self>`.